# In Linux, how do I go through each file and do a replace?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Suppose I want to go through each file (recursively too), and replace everything with:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}
```

with:

```
{% media_url %}/
```

What command can I run in Linux to replace the former with the latter, in all my files, recursively?

Comment: Would be a nice fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/. Removing the python and django tags --> not relevant here...

Comment: As usual: what have you tried already?  Oh, and why is this tagged as Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a sed solution...

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{% media_url %}\//g' {} \;
```

*Updated: added /g as per a commenter suggested*

*Updated: somehow unicode chars got copied in there*

Comment: Add a 'g' modifier to sed, to replace not only the first occurrence (which is probably what the OP wants)

Comment: There's an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `?'

Comment: Ah, and also: backslash-quoting the braces gives me an error. Since sed doesn't use extended regexps by default, I don't think you should use them (removing them works on my sed 4.2.1)

Comment: @all: thanks for the feedback on this; I'm updating my answer as you give feedback.

Comment: Double-quoting doesn't work either. The correct solution is quite simply find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{% media_url %}\//g' {} \;

Answer (score 3):

As much as possible, I use **xargs** instead of **-exec**.  With a **-exec**, you'll have one process launched for each file while with xargs you will have only one process.  You must use the sed option **-s** for that. This command is faster when you have several files:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -s -i 's/{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{% media_url %}\//g'
```

Comment: This might be outdated now but I've run into issues with xargs and very large number of file (>1024) which is why I avoided here. Your way may indeed be faster. Have you ever encountered what I am talking about?

Comment: Never. Xargs is able to split large number of files and execute several commands. You can use the -n option to control the max number of arguments.